# Close the App launched using intent when back pressed

Tags: android, android-intent

from my application "myApp",  I am launching separate Applications(say Application A,B,C and so on) using respective packagename in the intent with the following code:

```
Intent LaunchIntent =  getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packagename);

if(null!=LaunchIntent)
   {
      startActivity(LaunchIntent);
   }
```

Now, when i press back, i want to close the application launched. I don't have control over the application launched. Right now, when i press back i come back to "myApp", but the launched application's audio keeps playing in the background. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Feels like a bug in this application, it should stop playing audio when it's being closed. If you can access its source - you better fix this bug first.

Comment: No, i can't change its code.

Comment: Then it seems that you haven't got enough control over that application. You can't change the logic of how that application handles Back key without rewriting its code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, the audio is played in Service or an Activity and you are not familiar with [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ShuttingDown) and [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). If the audio is played in a Service, you must stop the Service in onBackPressed method. If the audio is in the Activity, you should add stop audio playback in overriden onPause method of the playing Activity. If you launch a third party app (and you can't access the code) you can't make it stop from your app.

Comment: No, I can't change its code. there is a dedicated close button in that app. if that is used, then it closes properly. if back button is pressed it keeps playing the audio. Anyways thanks for your answer. I had thought the same. I will wait for sometime to get answers from others. if i don't get any i will mark yours as answer.

Comment: If it's an audio player or something that runs in background, the stopping process is not related to it's Activity. It is impossible to stop programatically unless the author created a special intent or broadcast receiver for it.